# insert data using a loop doesn't promise sequential result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How to insert data into db with index as the title? I think this is typical async question but I can't solve it. The order of i been inserted not in sequence.

```
const { times } = require('lodash')

module.exports = (async () => {

  try {

    const createJob = async (i) => {

      console.log(i) //executed first 1 - 50 first
      const { data } = await axios
        .post('http://localhost:3000/job/create', {
          "title": i,
          "created_at": Date.now()
          })

      if(data) {
        console.log('job created. ', data)
      }
    }

    times(50, (i) => {
        createJob(++i)
    });

  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error creating ad. ', e)
  }
})()
```

Comment: What's `times`? Any reason you're not using a regular loop?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum lodash's times

Comment: `times(50, (i) => {
        createJob(++i)
    });` makes no sense. At best, it should be `times(50, createJob)`.

Comment: @Bergi it doesn't make any different at all, still have async problem

Comment: @Hoknimo Yes, that's why it's a comment. Like Benjamin said, just use a regular `for` loop in which you can `await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain your promises so each createJob is called after the previous one is finished. You can create an array of indexes and use array.reduce to do the chaining. In the code below, I replace your axios call with a `new Promise(...)`, just for simulating:

```js
var createJob = async (i) => {
    console.log(i) //executed first 1 - 50 first
    const { data } = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: i}), 1000));
    if (data) {
        console.log('job created. ', data);
    }  
    return data;
}

var arr = Array.from(new Array(10), (e, i) => i);
arr.reduce((m, o) => m.then(() => createJob(o)), Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: instead of reduce can we use other thing? didn't know reduce can accept Promise.resolve() as 2nd argument.

Comment: instead of reduce, a recursive approach maybe can be used

Comment: thanks mate, didn't know reduce can accept Promise.resolve!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Promise.all` to solve this. Essentially you save all the promises of the request in an array. Once, all the requests are complete, you can iterate over them.

```
const axios = require('axios');
module.exports = (async () => {

  try {

    const createJob = async (i, url) => {
      console.log(i, url) //executed first 1 - 50 first
      return axios.get(url);
    }

    const a = ['http://httpbin.org/anything/123', 'http://httpbin.org/anything/456']
    const promiseArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      promiseArray.push(createJob(j, a[j % 2]));
    }
    Promise.all(promiseArray).then((result) => {
      console.log('result', typeof (result));
      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log(result[i].data.url);
      }

    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error creating ad. ', e)
  }
})()
```

I have used `httpbin` for making actual calls and random payload to make sure the execution order is always the same.

Comment: Since the objective is to add records to db in specific order, Promise.all is likely unsuitable here.